# How do I wrap a call to a Google Apps Script function that accepts unlimited arguments

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, rhino

Some Google Apps Script functions like Logger.log() and Utility.formatString() accept unlimited arguments.

I would like to wrap a call to Logger.log() or Utility.formatString() so that in the innermost function call that I can prefix the resulting string with a timestamp and my own text. Usually you would just `.apply` the current module's ags to the function but in my testing this does not work as expected. It results in an error `TypeError: Cannot find default value for object. (line 14, file "Code")` which [looks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863810/error-trying-to-access-class-members-using-rhino) to be from the java/server side.

Here is the code I used for my test. Questions:

1. Is this a bug in these Apps Script methods?
2. Is there a workaround or alternative way to achieve my aim?

If it's a bug I will also file it on the issue tracker tracker

```
function testMyLogger() {
  myLogger('Testing %s %s %s', 'one', 2, 'three'); 
}

function myLogger()  {
  // do common things like prefix a timestamp to the first arg
    var logdate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    arguments[0]= logdate + " " + arguments[0]; 

  Logger.log.apply(this, arguments); 
  // At the above line I get error "TypeError: Cannot find default value for object. (line 14, file "Code")"
  // but I expected '<timestamp> Testing one 2.0 three' to the log (View > Logs...)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely unfortunate that this doesn't work, but `apply` and `map` often don't work well with functions on host objects (this is true in browsers too sometimes). However, this horrifyingly ugly hack will do the trick for you. Replace your `Logger.log.apply` with:

```
for (var i = 0, arr = []; i < arguments.length; ++i)
  arr.push('arguments[' + i + ']');
eval('Logger.log(' + arr.join() + ')');
```

Or, if one prefers conciseness to readability:

```
eval('Logger.log(' + [].slice.call(arguments, 0)
    .map(function(x, y){ return 'arguments[' + y + ']'; }).join() + ')');
```

**UPDATE**:

Or we could, you know, just fix the bug :)

I overstated the severity of the original bug: `call` and `apply` actually work on 95% of the methods on apps script host objects today, but you happened to hit one of the ones that doesn't currently work. Unfortunately, I can't explain the pattern to you for knowing which ones would work without referencing our internal code. Fortunately, one of my excellent colleagues diagnosed the problem and has already fixed it. `Logger.log.apply(Logger, ...)` will start working in a release or two. Keep an eye on the release notes.

Comment: Don't do that. Do `Logger.log.apply(Logger..`. Remember, the first argument to apply determines what the keyword `this` inside the function points to. It's almost always the object the method belongs to and almost never the current `this` value in the calling scope. A misunderstanding of how this works is why people think that `call` and `apply` don't work well with native objects - that's just not true

Comment: Nope, the canonical solution is genuinely not currently going to work in Apps Script. I say that as a member of the engineering team :) but you can easily verify it for yourself; we don't support apply on methods in our native objects.

Comment: Furthermore, it's often not true elsewhere either (for example, you cannot use apply on console.log in IE9 for similar reasons). Implementations of native objects are sometimes messier than you'd expect, and there's some wiggle room in the ES spec about native callables that makes this technically allowable by implementors.

Comment: I've tested and accepted @CoreyG's workaround. I used the first one as it will be readable when I stumble upon it in shock next year. btw Corey's been on the team for this product at the vendor (Google) so I am comfortable that the hack is the required workaround. Whether it will/can ever be made to work on the AppsScript native Logger objects is a matter for the implementors

Comment: FYI: The underlying bug should now be fixed. Using `call` or `apply` (the clean solution) appears to work correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Try `Logger.log.apply(Logger, arguments);`

Comment: Apologies chris, I corrected that call and have updated the error message (I tried a bunch of variations and initially wrote up the incorrect one here.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt to workaround the problem but this also returns the same error "TypeError: Cannot find default value for object".

Comment: FYI: The underlying bug should now be fixed. This is now the correct (working) answer.